# Sending params from Vue to Laravel controller to update props

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Wassup Folks,

I am building a Scrum Poker with longpolling, for that I want to use vue. I have used regular .blade templates beforehand.

I had clickable divs, that updated someoneone's card estimation on click like this:

```
<form action="{{route('sessions.values', $currentRoom->id)}}" id="1" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <input type="number" value="1" name="userValue" hidden />
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188234.svg" height="50" width="50" />
      </form>
```

Now I want to write a vue template template that holds in the whole room, including all participating user names, values, etc. with an option to update their estimation on click.

My vue looks currently like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">ID: {{roomNumber}}</span>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Raumname: {{roomName}}</span>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" v-for="(user,index) in currentUsers" :key="index">
      <!-- Show Json Debug is User is Admin -->
      <div v-if="user.isAdmin == 1">
        <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">{{output}}</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Show User Attributes for each user in room -->
      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">{{user.name}}</div>

      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" v-if="user.isAdmin == 1">Admin!</div>
      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" v-if="user.isAdmin !== 1">No Admin!</div>

      <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">{{user.pivot.userValue}}</div>
    </div>

    <div
      class="flex-left"
      onclick="document.getElementById('1').submit();"
      style="cursor: pointer;"
    >
      <form action="{{route('sessions.values', $currentRoom->id)}}" id="1" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <input type="number" value="1" name="userValue" hidden />
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188234.svg" height="50" width="50" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      output: "",
      roomNumber: "",
      roomName: "",
      currentUsers: "",
      userValue: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("/public/api/getPlayerInfo/" + this.$route.params.currentRoom)
      .then(response => {
        this.output = response.data;

        this.roomNumber = response.data.currentRoom.id;
        this.roomName = response.data.currentRoom.roomName;

        this.currentUsers = response.data.currentUsers;
        this.userValue = response.data.currentUsers.name;

        console.log(this.currentUsers);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  },
  methods: {
    getIDfromURL() {
      path = window.location.pathname;
      segments = path.split("/");
      return segments[2];
    },
    flash(message) {
      this.body = message;
      this.show = true;
      this.hide();
    },
    hide() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.show = false;
      }, 4000);
    }
  }
};
</script>
    <style>
.alert-flash {
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 25px;
}
</style>
```

cards.blade.php

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/child.blade.php -->



@extends('layouts.app')


@section('title', 'Scrumpoker')




@section('content')

<card></card>




@endsection
```

function that is called when starting to fetch room information

```
   public function getPlayerInfo($id)
    {
        $currentRoom = Session::findOrFail($id);
        $currentUsers = $currentRoom->users;


        $jsonData['currentRoom'] = $currentRoom;
        $jsonData['currentUsers'] = $currentUsers;



        return response()->json(['currentRoom' => $jsonData['currentRoom'], 'currentUsers' => $currentUsers]);
    }
```

Should I create a div with onclick, that sends the values to the controller? If yes, what would be a convient way for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are asking about the best way to implement the submission of the user's card value?

I'm not sure why there is only one card, but to submit the value of that card here's an example (I don't think you can use blade directives in Vue)

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

```
<div
    class="flex-left"
    v-on:click="$refs.card_form.submit()"
    style="cursor: pointer;"
>
    <form
        v-on:submit.prevent="submitCard(1)"
        ref="card_form"
        method="post"
    >
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188234.svg" height="50" width="50" />
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
export default{
    methods:{
        submitCard(card_value){
            axios.post('/values',{ userValue:card_value }) //not sure what your endpoint is
            .then(response=>{
                window.alert('value submitted')
            })
        }
    }

}
```